# ffmpeg Is not compitable with minikube

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, minikube

I have one pod in minikube which is for video editing task and I am using the moviepy library. There is issue occurring  Failed to read file duration and I debug the deep down code and found the cause with ffmpeg.

```
from __future__ import division

import logging
import os
import re
import subprocess as sp
import warnings

import numpy as np

from moviepy.compat import DEVNULL, PY3
from moviepy.config import get_setting  # ffmpeg, ffmpeg.exe, etc...
from moviepy.tools import cvsecs


is_GIF = False
cmd = [get_setting("FFMPEG_BINARY"), "-i", "https://videorenderingbucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/video_file/The+Breathtaking+Beauty+of+Nature+-+HD.mp4"]

if is_GIF:
  cmd += ["-f", "null", "/dev/null"]

popen_params = {"bufsize": 10**5,"stdout": sp.PIPE,"stderr": sp.PIPE,"stdin": DEVNULL}
if os.name == "nt":
    popen_params["creationflags"] = 0x08000000

proc = sp.Popen(cmd, **popen_params)
(output, error) = proc.communicate()
infos = error.decode('utf8')
print(infos)
```

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaTzv.png

Comment: …and your question is? Also, could you endeavour to post text as text, rather than pictures. Pictures of text cannot be indexed by google or read by software for the sight-impaired.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not ask a question

Comment: Even if it asked a question, this is much more suitable on StackOverflow, also. So remove here and post there. include a question with a ? at the end and also check for actual error, not just code. And don't post output as screenshot in the 1st place.